# Forward declaration и typedef

Tags: visual-c++, c, visual-studio

Есть структура

```
// struct.h
// -----------
typedef struct Type
{
    ...
} Synonim;
```

Также есть заголовочный файл с объявлениями функций, где параметром хочу сделать двойной указатель на Synonim. Вопрос: как правильно сделать forward decl (не включая туда struct.h напрямую) в заголовочнике с функциями, не получив ворнингов? У меня есть два варианта:

1) Объявить Synonim в качестве самостоятельной структуры:

```
struct Synonim;

void DoAction( struct Synonim** obj );

// warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
```

2) Объявить Synonim, как typedef от Type:

```
typedef struct Type Synonim;

void DoAction( Synonim** obj );

// warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'Synonim **' to 'Synonim **'
```

Comment: > void DoAction( struct Synonim** obj );

зачем тут в первом случае struct? Просто `void DoAction(Synonim** obj );` не работает?

Comment: 1)
Не работает, т.к. до этого объявляется структурой, что требует указания struct (Это Си, не С++). Без struct можно указывать typedef-синонимы типов, это будет как бы подстановка.

2)
Та же история. Type-тип там не известен.

Comment: У вас опечатка: один раз `Synonym`, потом `Synonim`.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил текст вопроса.

Comment: @Free_ze, хм, Си говорите - ну, и расширение файликов соответствующее и флаги компилятора тоже? Просто как-то странно говорить про Си при использовании MSVC++/CL.

Comment: @gecube С этим точно, "Compile as C Code (/TC)" в прожект пропертиз, *.c и stdlib во все поля. Студия умеет в C, хотя и не последние стандарты.
А то, что тулкит так выбран...корп. стандарт, ничего не поделать.

Comment: Как выглядит сама функция DoAction ?

Comment: @castaway не думаю, что это критично. Допустим:

void DoAction( SynonimXX obj )
{

   (Xobj)->value = 10;

}

, где X - *. Парсер лох.

Comment: Т.е. прототип выглядит так:
void DoAction( struct Synonim * * obj )
, а сама функция так:
void DoAction( Synonim * * obj )
 ?
Прототип соответствует заголовку функции?